# Enigmarch Day 2: Rhyme

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme

<sub>This puzzle was created as part of [Enigmarch](https://enigmarch.com/), a daily puzzle construction challenge.</sub>

---

*Read this carefully to find what you **need**;*

*Now that you've read this you won't be **misled**.*

```
glass case     4___
gross shows    _5___
clothes fuzz   _2__
stove glove    1___
clear air      _6__
pruned mound   __3__
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We are looking for

> Words that are spelled the same but have a different meaning with different pronunciation (i.e., homographs). In the example, we are given two words rhyming with **read** even though they don't rhyme with each other. Similarly we get
>
>  glass case: **B**ass
>  gross shows: c**L**ose
>  clothes fuzz: d**O**es
>  stove glove: **D**ove
>  clear air: t**E**ar
>  pruned mound: wo**U**nd
>
>  The answers are also in alphabetical order which verifies them. When we put the highlighted letters in the correct order, they spell out **DOUBLE**.